# What's the best approach towards implementing security for guest user requests in a stateless web API?

Tags: api, security, jwt, token, stateless

There is an existing stateful web API that is to be replaced with a stateless implementation.

Currently there are following types of active user sessions:

1. *Transient guest user* (has nothing worth saving, yet). 
   User has identifier, but doesn't have a password.
2. *Persistent guest user* (has some valuable data associated, e.g. shopping cart, favorites, etc).
   User has identifier, but doesn't have a password.
   Identified and authenticated via cookies. 
   Session can be converted to type 3 by registering.
   Session is dropped and a new session of type 3 is started on login.
3. *Persistent registered user* that is signed in. 
   User has identifier and a password.
   Identified and authenticated either via credentials or cookies. 
   Session is dropped on logout.

So I'm looking for some **best practices to implementing analogues for this three types of sessions in a stateless way.**

Looks like using a JWT token is quite a common practice for stateless authentication. Type 1 then looks pretty straight forward as requests don't need to be secured so there will be no token needed. Type 3 has lots of examples accross the web with generating JWT token based on user credentials. Type 2 is what confuses me as user has no password. I guess one thing that could be done is generating some password for persistent guest on backend and using it for token generation. Or is there a better way to handle this?

Also I'm trying to figure out what should happen to tokens when

- guest user registers (currently session is converted)
- guest user logs in (currently new session starts)

Answer (score 0):

We went with the following solution:

1. **Session types**. We reduced three session types to two: guest (not persistent) and user (persistent). Valuable guest information is now stored in cookies.
2. **JWT**. A token is stored in a secure HttpOnly cookie. Token contains user id, user type, issue date and expiry time. Token is encrypted using secret key and set as a response cookie at backend when new guest is generated or when user logs in.

So now we are in an intermediate state where we have both stateless and stateful APIs inside our monolith and there are two security mechanisms working at the same time.
Next step is to extract stateless services.

P.S. If you encounter a similar problem you can also consider using a stateful API gateway in front of your stateless services. That gives certain benefits, you can google that for more info.